# Can i show modal bottom sheet at app launch flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

Am trying to show `bottom sheeet` at app launch automatically in flutter, but it comes with errors. It only works for me when I instantiate it with a click event. But how can i pop it on screen launch?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can do so in the initState of your first screen, like so

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0)).then((_) {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (builder) {
            return Container();
          });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

you need to do it like that, using future and delayed becuase initState dosent allow .of inside it, this is kinda hack but it works

Answer (score 8):

**Simple Solution**

```
@override
  void initState() {
   
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container();
    });
    });

  }
```

Comment: This comes down to opinion as both this and the other answer work, but I think the intent with this one is clearer.

Comment: Brilliant, save my day!